# Android: Measuring child with sizes defined in its xml

Tags: android

I would like to know how to measure child view with width and height value which are defined  in child's xml file.

I know that in `onMeasure()` method of my custom `ViewGroup` I should call:

```
child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

But how to get `childWidth` and `childHeight` from xml code?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question. Essentially you want to use [measureChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#measureChild%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int%29) function provided by the ViewGroup.  This function will take care of measuring it properly.

Comment: It's exactly the same as `child.measure()` but in this case you just pass the child as the first parameter.

Comment: No, I don't think it is the same. I'm not yet sure of the nuances of the measurement and layout lifecycle, but calling child.measure() was not  measuring the child correctly (it was ignoring the specific heigh I assigned it and doing wrap_content instead). When I replaced the call to measureChild() it worked as expected. If someone could elaborate on the differences between these two calls it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can get them from [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) of the child:

```
LayoutParams l = child.getLayoutParams();
childWidth = l.width;
childHeight = l.height;
```

ViewGroup's constructors are capable of reading the `layout_height` and `layout_width` parameters from xml.

Comment: I tried this, but I get null instead of `LayoutParams` object

Comment: @teoREtik, can you post sources of your ViewGroup? I've tried to extend ViewGroup  myself and I can see that there is no `null` layout params for children. What is your base class and what methods are you overriding?

Comment: My base class is AdapterView, actually and I add and measure it's children in `onLayout()` method.

Comment: The you are inflating child views in adapter, aren't you? If you are using `LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.foo, parent, false)` then it should correctly create layout params based on `foo.xml` contents unless you overrode generateLayoutParams in your view.

Comment: Yes you're right I inflate it from adapter and don't override generateLayoutParams

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot figure out why you are getting `null` for layout params. May be you will find something useful in [this article about extending AdapterView](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/).

Comment: The most funny is that I'm just making my custom view basing on this article.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but the values in my layoutparams aren't the same as the ones specified (in dip) in the xml.  Do I have to convert?

Comment: @Dapp, yes, these runtime values are in pixels. They are already scaled from dp according to device's DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
    (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
childWidth = params.width;
childHeight = params.height;
```

in the above code replace the `RelativeLayout` with the your parent layout

Comment: Look at my comment for Darth Beleg